# Fetching full name from Active Directory using C# doesn't work after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory, ldap

I'm fetching a user's full name from the server using the following code:

```
public string getUserName(int empID)
        {

            DirectoryEntry objDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://SOMEDOMAIN.com");
            objDirectoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

            DirectorySearcher objDirectorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(objDirectoryEntry);
            objDirectorySearch.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + empID + ")";
            objDirectorySearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

            SearchResult objSearchResult = objDirectorySearch.FindOne();

            if (objSearchResult != null)

                return Convert.ToString(objSearchResult.Properties["displayname"][0]);

            else

                return "User not found";

        }
```

This works perfectly fine on my local machine.

However, after deploying this to the server, it doesn't work at all.

This returns NULL.

As @marc_s suggested I tried using the following code :

```
public string getUserStackExchange(string empID)
        {
            string fullName = empID;
            // set up domain context using the default domain you're currently logged in 
            using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                // find a user
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, empID);

                /* or if you're interested in the *currently logged in* user,
                   then you could also use:
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
                */

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // get the "DisplayName" property ("Fullname" is WinNT specific)
                    fullName = user.DisplayName;

                    // do something here....        
                }
            }
            return fullName;
        }
```

Same result. Works perfectly fine in local. But it doesn't work after deployment.
However,If I run the project in Debug mode with breakpoints on, It fetches data perfectly.

Is there something wrong with the code or IIS configuration (I suspect this)?

Comment: Learn to log what you are doing and to debug your own code.

Comment: The `WinNT://` provider is for your local machine user store - it is **NOT** the Active Directory - the network-based storage! You need to use the `LDAP://` provider for this!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks.. I've tried using LDAP. The result is same. works fine in local. doesn't work on server. please check the updated question.

Comment: The property is called `displayName` (not `displayname` - yes, I think it's actually **case-sensitive**) - try with the correct spelling - does that return a value? Or maybe that value just isn't set on that user account ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context using the default domain you're currently logged in 
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Environment.UserName);

    /* or if you're interested in the *currently logged in* user,
       then you could also use:
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
    */

    if(user != null)
    {
        // get the "DisplayName" property ("Fullname" is WinNT specific)
        string fullName = user.DisplayName; 

        // do something here....        
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I've tried using it. the same thing happens here too.
It runs fine in local. but after deployment it doesn't work.
however,
If i run the project in Debug mode with breakpoints on. it works fine.
I suspect there's something wrong with IIS. What do you think @marc_s?